# Can anybody suggest me some graph generating ways using python/django/jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I also want to save the generated graph as an image (or generate image of graph) for appending to pdf..I tried **jqplot(jquery)**,**cairoplot(python)** but that is not satisfying my requirements.

Comment: 'matplotlib' is a python library for graph generation. Here - http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/installing.html

Comment: d3.js is a powerful javascript library for creating visualizations. http://d3js.org/

Comment: @Tanveer Alam thank you..Using matplotlib I can save graph as image. But now I can't install in it my virtual environment(pip install python-matplotlib).Do i need to add matplotlib repository

Comment: @TanveerAlam I installed matplotlib. There is one problem while generating bar graph. If there is only one data like shown below,the width of the graph is covering the whole area,evenif the width is set. Example :  x = [3]
                y = [10]
                bar(x, y, width=0.2,align='center')

Comment: @user123 - You should ask that question in stackoveflow separately, because even i tried for single value and its covering whole area even by assigning width to it.

Comment: @TanveerAlam I asked & got answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217902/how-to-set-matplotlib-bar-graph-width-when-there-is-only-one-data/23222168?noredirect=1#23222168

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a single plugin to solve both these requirement but if you are fine with using more than one plugin try **Google Charts** for plotting the graph and **HTML2CANVAS** for saving its image as png.

- https://developers.google.com/chart/
- http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/