# how to set matplotlib bar graph width when there is only one data

Tags: matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to generate a graph. There is one problem while generating bar graph. If there is only one data like shown below,the width of the graph is covering the whole area,evenif the width is set. 
Example :

```
     x = [3] 
     y = [10] 
     bar(x, y, width=0.2,align='center')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `width` controls the width of the bar in 'data' units.  By default the limits of the graph are auto-scaled to your data limits, in this case that is the width of your single bar.   You just need the axis limits.

```
x = [3]
y = [10]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.bar(x, y, width=0.2)
ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could somebody please subtitle this answer? And what is the "width of a 'data' unit" in the case of datetimes?