# Adjusting width of single data barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphing

I am automating making reports based on particular locations. Certain graphs contain bar graphs with only one bar and they span the width of the graph[image: (second graph in attached picture)]. I tried using `axes.set_xlim(0, len(data)-1)` but ended up with the graph looking like the top one in the attached picture, if there are more than one bars. When I have multiple bars, usually leaving out `axes.set_xlim` gives a decent graph (last graph in picture). I know using [width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217902/how-to-set-matplotlib-bar-graph-width-when-there-is-only-one-data) in the graph will only work is there are two or more bars.

I used len(data) since data is a list and the length would tell me how many bars are going to pop up.
My graph code is within a for loop, so each iteration will have a different length for data

Is there a way to adjust the widths accordingly?

Comment: set the limits to `ax.set_xlim(-0.5, len(data)-0.5)` and the width as `width=min(1-1/(len(data)+1), 0.8)`

Comment: This works great! Also clever what you ended up doing with the width, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest